# Android Studio : Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGNw0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7uKh.png)
This error is also reported when deleting and downloading Android Studio again,Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Normal opening of the simulator

Comment: maybe because of your internet connection? Did you use local network of your company & they block something?

Comment: Please install command line tools and accept licences as well as per first screenshot provided

Comment: @Nguyen family   , No, the company network has not set up interception